# What's the meaning of the phrase "Are you a man or a mouse?"

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms

Today, my teacher gave me an assignment to write down a conversation using the phrase:

> *Are you a man or a mouse?*

I don't know what that phrase means, can you please help me with this?

Comment: Not giving a full answer since it's homework, but it means the same as: *Are you a man, or are you a mouse?* What are the biggest differences between being a man and being a mouse?

Answer (score 1):

A mouse will run away from danger. When someone says, "Are you a man or a mouse?", they are saying, "Don't be a coward like a mouse. Be courageous like a man."

It is generally used when you are trying to make a scared man do something dangerous (like charge into battle).